# "while read LINE do" and grep problems

Tags: bash, grep, while-loop, cat

I have two files.

```
file1.txt:  
Afghans  
Africans  
Alaskans  
...
```

where `file2.txt` contains the output from a wget on a webpage, so it's a big sloppy mess, but does contain many of the words from the first list.

Bashscript:

```
cat file1.txt | while read LINE; do grep $LINE file2.txt; done
```

This did not work as expected.  I wondered why, so I echoed out the $LINE variable inside the loop and added a sleep 1, so i could see what was happening:

```
cat file1.txt | while read LINE; do echo $LINE; sleep 1; grep $LINE file2.txt; done
```

The output looks in terminal looks something like this:

> Afghans
>   Africans
>   Alaskans
>   Albanians
>   Americans
>   grep: Chinese: No such file or directory
>   : No such file or directory
>   Arabians
>   Arabs
>   Arabs/East Indians
>   : No such file or directory
>   Argentinans
>   Armenians
>   Asian
>   Asian Indians
>   : No such file or directory
>   file2.txt: Asian Naruto
>   ...

So you can see it did finally find the word "Asian". But why does it say:

> No such file or directory

?

Is there something weird going on or am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you simply asking what is going on? Or are you asking for a solution to writing the script?

Comment: i definitely want to know why it's not working, but i'm open to learning by an example of a working version, make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@OP, First, use `dos2unix` as advised. Then use awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next}{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i in a) {print $i} } } '  file1 file2_wget
```

Note: using while loop and grep inside the loop is not efficient, since for every iteration, you need to invoke `grep` on the file2.

@OP, crude explanation:
For meaning of FNR and NR, please refer to [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/). `FNR==NR{a[1];next}`  means getting the contents of file1 into array `a`. when  FNR is not equal to NR (which means reading the 2nd file now), it will check if each word in the file is in array `a`. If it is, print out. (the for loop is used to iterate each word)

Comment: that works!  very cool.  Could I trouble you to (briefly) explain what that does?  Awk is something I know little about.  I would really like to understand how this works.  Thanks buddy!

Comment: I say briefly for your benefit by the way, if you'd like to to school me on it, I wouldnt object at all...

Answer (score 5):

What about

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Use more quotes and use less `cat`

```
while IFS= read -r LINE; do 
  grep "$LINE" file2.txt
done < file1.txt
```

Comment: In this case `grep` will consume all the input intended for `read` (which is also not file2.txt).

Answer (score 1):

As well as the quoting issue, the file you've downloaded contains CRLF line endings which are throwing `read` off. Use `dos2unix` to convert file1.txt before iterating over it.

Comment: interesting.  you've provided me with 2 solutions for me already.  Thank you.  But I am still a bit confused.  I just created a test file that contains one of the first items in file1.txt.  I used the same command, with "$LINE", and it does not find it through grep.  Any idea why?

Comment: What line ending does this new file use?

Comment: edited... (sorry i misread)  it should be newline, i used vi to make it.  Does that answer?

Comment: okay i hope you havent gotten tired of me yet ;)  I used :set invlist in vim, and found out it's "$" for the line endings.  Does that mean I need to set the IFS=$ ?  Maybe you could give me a final push in the right direction, and i'll be able to figure this out?

Comment: vi is capable of creating files with any line ending. Use `dos2unix` to be certain that the file uses LF line endings.

Answer (score 1):

Although usng awk is faster, grep produces a lot more details with less effort. So, after issuing **dos2unix** use:

`grep -F -i -n -f <file_containing_pattern> <file_containing_data_blob>`

You will have all the matches + line numbers (case insensitive)

At minimum this will suffice to find all the words from file_containing_pattern:

```
grep -F -f <file_containing_pattern> <file_containing_data_blob>
```